# Nutch Crawler taking very long

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch

I only want Nutch to give me a list of the urls it crawled and the status of that link. I do not need the entire page content or fluff. Is there a way I can do this? Crawling a seedlist of 991 urls with a depth of 3 takes over 3 hours to crawl and parse. I'm hoping this will speed things up.

In the nutch-default.xml file there is

```
<property>
  <name>file.content.limit</name>
  <value>65536</value>
  <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the file
   protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
   than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
   confuse this setting with the http.content.limit setting.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>file.content.ignored</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>If true, no file content will be saved during fetch.
  And it is probably what we want to set most of time, since file:// URLs
  are meant to be local and we can always use them directly at parsing
  and indexing stages. Otherwise file contents will be saved.
  !! NO IMPLEMENTED YET !!
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>http.content.limit</name>
  <value>65536</value>
  <description>The length limit for downloaded content using the http
  protocol, in bytes. If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer
  than it will be truncated; otherwise, no truncation at all. Do not
  confuse this setting with the file.content.limit setting.
  </description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>ftp.content.limit</name>
  <value>65536</value> 
  <description>The length limit for downloaded content, in bytes.
  If this value is nonnegative (>=0), content longer than it will be truncated;
  otherwise, no truncation at all.
  Caution: classical ftp RFCs never defines partial transfer and, in fact,
  some ftp servers out there do not handle client side forced close-down very
  well. Our implementation tries its best to handle such situations smoothly.
  </description>
</property>
```

These properties are ones I think may have something to do with it but i'm not sure. Can someone give me some help and clarification? Also I was getting many urls with the status code of 38. I cannot find what that status code indicates in [this](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/nutch/trunk/src/java/org/apache/nutch/crawl/CrawlDatum.java?view=markup) document. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Nutch performs parsing after fetching the URL, to get all the outlinks from the fetched URL. The outlinks from a URL are used as the new fetchlist for the next round.

If parsing is skipped, no new URLs might be generated and hence no more fetching. 
One way I can think of is to configure the parse plugins to include only the type of content you require to be parsed(in your case its the outlinks).
One example here - https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/IndexMetatags

This links describes the features of the parser https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/Features

Now, to get only the list of the URLs fetched with their statuses you can use the

`$bin/nutch readdb crawldb -stats` command.

Regarding the status code of 38, looking at the document you have linked, it seems like the status of the URL is 
`public static final byte STATUS_FETCH_NOTMODIFIED = 0x26`

Since, Hex(26) corresponds to Dec(38).

Hope the answer gives some direction :)

Comment: Wow, I have no clue why I didn't think of converting it from hex to dec for the status id, thanks for that. I have been able to speed things up dramatically by upping the # of threads I use. This has reduced the time to make that same crawl down to 6 minutes. However the extra "fluff" is still there. I cannot figure out the parsing thing as you have described here. In my database I only want to see 2 fields; an id (being the url tested itself), and the status (being the status of the url after fetching).

Comment: The `bin/nutch readdb crawldb -stats` command only shows me an overall stats broken down by status ids and the number of urls per. This is not my end goal but it is still informative.

Comment: if you want the status broken down by each URL. Use the bin/nutch readdb crawldb -stats -sort